# server only pulls using linked card

Tags: lua, minecraft, opencomputers

I have a server that forwards messages from a Linked card to another server with a Network card. This works fine, server 1 (with the linked card) pulls a message from pc, and sends it to server 2(using a network card). the following part doesn't work:

server 1 pulls again, and receives from server 2 using a network card, and server 1 sends that message over to the pc using a linked card.

The problem is that server 1 needs to pull via a network card, and a linked card. server 1 always pulls using the linked card, but not with the network card. is there any way to fix this?

(sorry for bad English)

I use the following code to pull:

```
local _, _, from, port, _, message = event.pull("modem_message")
```

Comment: To clarify, you have a computer with one network card and one linked card, both "listening" to incoming modem_messages, but it only uses the linked card no matter what?

Comment: And the moment you turn off/remove the linked card, the network card starts working again?

Comment: yes. if I remove the linked card, and reboot the program, it works fine on the network card

Comment: Since this question seems quite specific I suggest you ask in the OpenComputers forum with a minimal example.